# Watching TypeScript module vars in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 2RC (TypeScript 1.0), although the following code works, if you set a breakpoint on `age` and hover over it, nothing appears. You have to watch `Test.age`.
But the code is correct, isn't it?

```
module Test
{
    export var age: number;

    export function go()
    {
        age = 40;
        return age; // put a breakpoint here, and hover over age
    }
}

Test.go();
```

Notice if you do not export `age`, the debugging works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

The VS debugger and TypeScript source map emitter don't yet implement symbol mapping. To understand what's going on, look at the generated code:

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    Test.age;

    function go() {
        Test.age = 40;
        return Test.age;
    }
    Test.go = go;
})(Test || (Test = {}));

Test.go();
```

Note that there is no *variable* named `age` in scope at any point, only a property called `age` on the `Test` module.

Contrast this to the generated code to if you had removed `export` from `age`:

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    var age;

    function go() {
        age = 40;
        return age;
    }
    Test.go = go;
})(Test || (Test = {}));

Test.go();
```

Here, `age` does exist and the debugger can find it.

Comment: So this is a known deficiency in the debugger, and we should always reference `Test.age` in this case?